# I want to add a parameter to string

Tags: c#, string

I want to add a parameter to specific string but i tryed a few things a none of them work any idea how to make it work ?
Thanks

```
string dummyData = "data to insert";
string stringinfo = @"{
                                    'result': {
                                        's3o_path': 'dummyData',
                                    },
                                    'statusCode': '200'
                                }";
string stringinfo = @"{
                                    'result': {
                                        's3o_path': '{dummyData}',
                                    },
                                    'statusCode': '200'
                                }";
string stringinfo = @"{
                                    'result': {
                                        's3o_path': ''dummyData'',
                                    },
                                    'statusCode': '200'
                                }";
string stringinfo = @"{
                                    'result': {
                                        's3o_path': ''{dummyData}'',
                                    },
                                    'statusCode': '200'
                                }";
stringinfo = string.Format(stringinfo,dummyData);

string dummyData = _fixture.Create<string>();
        string httpResponse = @"{
                                    'result': {
                                        's3o_path': '#dummyData#',
                                    },
                                    'statusCode': '200'
                                }";
        httpResponse = httpResponse.Replace("#dummyData#",dummyData);
```

the last way it was the only way i found to to make it work any better idea would be good

Comment: You need: `${dummyData}` - note the `$`.

Comment: Use something like JSON.net, too. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Steve is correct in his comment. The easiest way to get what it seems you are going for is to add the Nuget package Json.NET and utilize the Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject.

The code should look something like (you can copy and paste into LINQPad to run be sure to add the Nuget package and include the using statement):

```
void Main()
{
    string dummyData = "data to insert";
    var dataObject = new DataObject
    {
        result = new Result { s3o_path = $"{dummyData}" },
        statusCode = 200
    };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataObject);
    Console.WriteLine(json);

  // output will be {"result":{"s3o_path":"data to insert"},"statusCode":200}

}

public class DataObject {
    public Result result {get;set;}
    public int statusCode {get;set;} // use int instead of string for status code
}

public class Result {
    public string s3o_path {get;set;}
}
```